# Django Search Many to Many Query

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to do a query a **search** with a **ManyToMany** Relationship,
This is what I have so far:

```
designs = designs.filter(Q(title__icontains = search) | 
                         Q(tags__icontains = search))
```

Do you know how I can search the tags.title field in the query?

Here are the Models, I cleaned them up so they arent so long :)

```
class Design(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default = "")
    slug = models.SlugField(unique = True)   
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = "design_user")
    description = models.TextField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(to = Tags)

class Tags(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 50, unique = True)

    # Allows the category to list as a dropdown in the admin
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

*Most of the questions I looked up are using filters and I'm no Django master so I am asking this hopefully not adding a duplicate question.*

Comment: Are you looking for `tags__title__icontains = search` ?

Comment: plz copy paste your model definitions the problem will be easy to understand.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do it with the proper `field_lookup`: `tags__title__icontains = search`:

```
designs = designs.filter(Q(title__icontains = search) | 
                         Q(tags__icontains = search)  |
                         Q(tags__title__icontains = search))
```

Fields lookups are very useful, you should take a look at [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups).

Comment: Yes that is right! I had tries Q(tags_title__icontains) missing and underscore so I thought I was a lost cause! Thanks so much this works perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `tags__title__icontains` as

```
designs = designs.filter(Q(title__icontains = search) | 
                         Q(tags__title__icontains = search))
```